# TERM variable in chroot

Tags: debian, environment-variables, chroot

I've created a chroot with the help of jailkit and now I'm trying to install some other libraries and tools.

First I tried to install `clear` library. I've copied the file from the `/bin` folder and copied the dependencies to the chroot. However, when I entered the `clear` command, it says:

> TERM environment variable not set.

So, when I'm logged in as root, the value of `TERM` is `xterm-256color`. But when I enter `export TERM=xterm-256color`, it says unknown terminal type.

What should I do?

Comment: What exact commands did you use to enter the chroot and run `clear`?

Answer (score 4):

`clear` depends on terminfo. terminfo uses the value of `$TERM` as a key to look up the proper escape sequences for your terminal in its database. You need to copy the terminfo database files for the terminal types you want to be supported in the chroot. You'll find them in `/lib/terminfo` or `/usr/share/terminfo`. If the files aren't found, terminfo can't do anything but tell you that it doesn't recognize your terminal type.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to install a shell in the chroot.

Also, debian has a very useful tool for populating chroots with a debian system, look at the man page for debbootstrap for more.

Answer (score 0):

A good suggestion from the [Gentoo alt-install doc](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/altinstall.xml#doc_chap3): Instead of `chroot /your/chroot/path /bin/bash` run

```
chroot /your/chroot/path /bin/env -i TERM=$TERM /bin/bash
```

`env -i` will clean the environment (the chroot-environment is probably different or even incompatible), while the `TERM=$TERM` will make the `chroot`ed `bash` aware of the parent's `TERM` variable (`$TERM` is expanded by the parent shell before executing the commands).